# Change Size of a View in a Thread insn´t the UI Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, ui-thread

I have a View, a RelativeLayout "gesLayout". When the size of "gesLayout" changes it calls the method "resize".

```
gesLayout = new RelativeLayout(this) {
        @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
            resize(); // -> bei Resize die Elemente neu anordnen.
            super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        }
    };
```

Here is the resize method:

```
private void resize() {

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable()  {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = layButtons.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = 500;
            layButtons.setLayoutParams(params);

            layButtons.invalidate();

        }
    });
}
```

But the height of the other Layout is not changing. But when I run the same code, which is in the resize()-method, after a button is clicked it is working perfect.

So my question: How can I access the UI Thread from here? As you can seethe  runOnUiThread()-method is not working.

P.S. I already checked that the resize()-method is called correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the layout params, you need to call requestLayout to lay it out again.

Comment: I tried this before but without any effect. And as I said before: "But when I run the same code, which is in the resize()-method, after a button is clicked it is working perfect."

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `onSizeChanged()` is called in GPU thread, not main thread.

All the layout params changes should be done in main/UI thread instead. You can use method to post the change to UI thread.

```
private void resize() {

    layButtons.post(new Runnable()  {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = layButtons.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = 500;
            layButtons.setLayoutParams(params);

            layButtons.invalidate();

        }
    });
}
```